# Redirecting looped grep commands to separate files

Tags: bash, grep

I'd like to use grep to recursively search through a directory, using patterns listed in a file, then store each result in its own file for reference later.

I made an attempt (using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/bash-scripting-read-file-line-by-line) as a guide) and came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p grep_results   # For storing results

echo "Performing grep searches.."
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "Seaching for $line.."
    grep -r "$line" --exclude-dir=grep_results . > ./grep_results/"$line"_infile.txt
done

echo "Done."
```

However, when I run it, the console hangs until I hit CTRL-C:

```
$ bash grep_search.sh search_terms.txt
Performing grep searches..
```

Where is the issue with this script? Or am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: on this line `grep -r "$line" --exclude-dir=grep_results > ./grep_results/"$line"_infile.txt`, I'm unable to see a file name to be looked into. That might be the reason why it hangs until ctrl-c is pressed.

Comment: Well spotted! Unfortunately it's still not working. I modified my post to include the edited line.

Comment: Similar to the previous issue, what is `read` reading from? Are you manually typing in search strings? Did you mean to run `bash grep_search.sh < search_terms.txt`? (Also note that `bash` can read patterns from a file. Check out the `-f` option.)

Comment: That was the issue, I wasn't directing in search_terms.txt! Thanks muru, working as expected now

Comment: @MelBurslan no, `grep -r` will be run on the current directory by default. That wasn't a problem. The `-r` flag makes `grep` run on all files in the current directory recursively.

Comment: Ah. In my previous comment, I meant to say *`grep`*
 can read patterns from a file.

Comment: You're almost always approaching it wrong if you're using `while..read` to process text... Just curious, what's in your pattern file - GACT sequences ? This would be a great question if it had a bit more detail/clarity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. The `while` loop isn't reading any input. The correct format is

   ```
   while read line; do ... ; done < input file
   ```

   Or

   ```
   some other command | while read ...
   ```

   Your loop is therefore hanging, waiting for input. You can test this by running your script and then typing anything and hitting enter (here, I entered `foo`):

   ```
   $ foo.sh 
   Performing grep searches..
   foo
   Searching for foo..
   ```

   You can improve this by adding a prompt to your `read`:

   ```
   while IFS='' read -p "Enter a search pattern: " -r line ...
   ```

   That will still run until you stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> though.
2. The `|| [[ -n "$line" ]]` (which means "OR the variable $line is not empty") is never executed. Since `read` hangs, the "OR" is never reached. I don't understand what you wanted it to do anyway. If you want to search for `$line` if `$line` is defined and use `read` if it is not, you'd need something like:

   ```
   if [[ -n "$line" ]]; then
        grep -r "$line" --exclude-dir=grep_results > ./grep_results/"$line"_infile.txt
   else
       while IFS='' read -p "Enter a search pattern: " -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
         grep -r "$line" --exclude-dir=grep_results > ./grep_results/"$line"_infile.txt
       done
   fi
   ```

   Here, if `$line` is not defined, you still need to enter it manually. A cleaner approach would be to either feed a file to the `while` loop:

   ```
   while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
     grep -r "$line" --exclude-dir=grep_results > ./grep_results/"$line"_infile.txt
   done < list_of_patterns.txt
   ```

Comment: The intention was to direct list of patterns in a file at it - so multiple sets of patterns can be saved and used as and when. The `|| [[ -n "$line" ]]` bit was there on recommendation from the answer to the question linked in my original post (_prevents the last line from being ignored if it doesn't end with a \n (since read returns a non-zero exit code when it encounters EOF)._)

Your answer definitely helped me make sense of it though, thanks!